# How to run dataproc cluster in cluster mode?

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

We are trying to run the Dataproc cluster in a cluster mode, but failing to do so. We have tried the property `--properties spark.submit.deployMode=cluster`, but failed.

Can someone give more info on how to setup?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the problem is that you didn't specify `spark:` prefix when setting `spark.submit.deployMode` property during cluster creation.

In Dataproc, if you set properties during cluster creation time you need prefix them with the component that you are setting them for, see [Dataproc cluster properties documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/cluster-properties) for details.

This command should work to create cluster on which Spark jobs will be submitted in cluster mode:

```sh
CLUSTER_NAME=<cluster_name>
gcloud dataproc clusters create ${CLUSTER_NAME} \
  --properties=spark:spark.submit.deployMode=cluster
```

Note, that in cluster mode Dataproc will not be able to stream Spark driver output in gcloud and Cloud Console.